# Does :new & :old prefix work on other columns when update is done to a row in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

A table with two attributes, `A` & `B`, and a row-level trigger that will be fired after updating attribute `B`. My question is can I use `:new` or `:old` prefix to attribute `A`? If yes, which one should I use? Thanks.

Comment: Give it a try on a test table. This is a simple test to set up :-) Learning by doing will help it "stick" better too.Take notes for yourself while you are at it and save the commented code in a folder for future reference. Enjoy the learning process and pass on your knowledge when you can, grasshopper.  Make the journey as enjoyable as the destination.

Comment: btw, tables have columns ;)

Comment: @Gary_W I'll definitely do so tomorrow in my Uni's lab. In fact, I'm on Linux and the installation of oracle server on this platform is a pain. And I've not enough memory to dual-boot Windows or run it on a virtual environment. So what can I do is just writing the code and test it the next day.

Answer (score 1):

You can use whichever is appropriate for what you want to do:

- :old.a is the value before the update
- :new.a is the value after the update

Comment: I understand the difference between :new & :old. In my case, however, attribute A remains unchanged after the update is done to B, which makes the use of :new & :old become rather meaningless. If I am allowed to use them, I'm guessing :old is more appropriate. I just want to have a confirmation from this question. Thanks for answering though.

Comment: If the value is unchanged then both contain this same value.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TDDDG/tdddg_triggers.htm#TDDDG99934):

> For an UPDATE trigger, OLD contains the old values, and NEW contains the new values

with both :OLD and :NEW are records. They won't only have the changed values, but the whole record.

Comment: So, what you mean is that even if I update a single attribute to a certain row, all of the values of that particular row will be considered as :new although they remain unchanged?

Comment: indeed, it would be a bit illogical to give only the changed values but presenting it as a record